# Pug template isn't rendering raw HTML passed to it

Tags: html, node.js, express, templates, pug

I have a pug template that is rendered and shown to the user when a button is clicked on my web page. I have an issue with pug rendering HTML tags as part raw text instead of parsing the text and adding it as a DOM node.

My pug template looks like: `p #{object.property}` so trying to interpolate an HTML string into the template.

The property contains an HTML string that looks like:

`<p>Here is some text I'm trying to render</p>`

I have tried just using `#{object.property}` to strange rendering issues where it renders `<` in the page followed by the text content. I'm pretty sure this is caused by pug reading the `<` as plain text and the `p` as a pug element which makes sense.

This is what the render looks like on the rendered web page.

```
<
Here is some text I'm trying to render

>Here is some text I'm trying to render

>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is having reference to a valid HTML string in my pug template and have pug render it as a DOM node.

Having the HTML string without tags is unfortunately out of the question.

Any responses are much appreciated.

> Note: Using Pug 2.0.0-beta-11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to preserve HTML in a string passed to the template, you need to use unescaped string interpolation. Instead of the number sign before brackets, you need an exclamation point. So `#{object.property}` should be `!{object.property}`

Comment: So all that does is create an "unexpected text" error at the column where the "!" appears. I believe this syntax was valid in earlier versions of Jade though.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it does work but only if you explicitly define a parent element. So `div !{object.property}` works but `!{object.property}` on its own doesn't. I haven't extensively tested this theory but that's my understanding so far. Thanks for the heads up though! +1

Comment: @ForrestWilson, Can you please provide an example for your explanation. I have kept my code like div !{props}, but it is showing error

Comment: @sony, @ForrestWilson so if you do `| !{object.property}` or `!= object.property` it should work