# How do I echo some HTML within a pug loop?

Tags: html, pug, preprocessor

I'm trying to do this with pug 2.0.3:

```
- var myCode = "<i class='icon fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true' data-aos='zoom-in'></i>";
- var i = 0;

while i < 10
  !{myCode}
  i++
```

I'm expecting the contents of `myCode` to be compiled into the HTML ten times, but instead I'm getting this error:
`unexpected text "!{myC"`

How do I make pug echo some unescaped html within a loop?

Comment: Did you try `div !{myCode}`? Pug requires a tag name for output ([*ref*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48967629/1813169))

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pug should do the trick, and [here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/graham-sportsmgmt/pen/rPddVW) with it live (you have to inspect using dev tools to see what it does as there are no visible elements).

This pug:

```
- var i = 0
while i < 10
  div(class='hidden-' + i)
  div
    i.icon.fa.fa-heart(aria-hidden='true' data-aos='zoom-in')
  - i++
```

Produces this html:

```
<div class="hidden-0"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-1"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-2"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-3"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-4"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-5"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-6"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-7"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-8"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
<div class="hidden-9"></div>
<div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
```

If you want the div with the i/icon to be inside the hidden-X div instead then just indent it like this:

```
- var i = 0
while i < 10
  div(class='hidden-' + i)
    div
      i.icon.fa.fa-heart(aria-hidden='true' data-aos='zoom-in')
  - i++
```

Which produces this:

```
<div class="hidden-0">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-1">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-2">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-3">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-4">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-5">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-6">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-7">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-8">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-9">
  <div><i class="icon fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" data-aos="zoom-in"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working loop:

```
while i < 10
    div(class="hidden-" + i++)
    div !{myCode}
```

I couldn't find a way to "silently" iterate over `i` so I had to make a dummy class for that.

Compiled HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="hidden-0"></div>
<div><i class='icon fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true' data-aos='zoom-in'></i></div>
<div class="hidden-1"></div>
<div><i class='icon fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true' data-aos='zoom-in'></i></div>
...
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to i++ without having to compile it to HTML let me know :)